# Rendering terminal output in the browser

Tags: html, bash, logging, terminal, ansi-escape

I have a file with a bunch of terminal logs captured with the `screen` utility. Here's a snippet:

```
[A[0m[27m[24m[J[34m~[39m


(base) [38;5;242mbase[39m [35m❯[39m ]133;B[K[?1l>[?2004l

[A[0m[27m[24m[J[34m~[39m
```

etc etc etc.

The output is full of ANSI escape codes, \r, \n, etc. Yet my terminal manages to render it all quite nicely, and I imagine I ought to be able to as well. I have found some libraries that convert ANSI codes to HTML, but I don't think they handle any of the other escaping.

I still feel like someone must have solved this problem, somehow, before me. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're many nice answers at [an old SE post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44956/converting-colored-output-into-html)
Depending on your environment, you may find some other packages to

- [NodeJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ansi-to-html) at [github](https://github.com/rburns/ansi-to-html)
- [another JS](https://github.com/drudru/ansi_up)
- [Python](https://pypi.org/project/ansi2html/) at [github](https://github.com/ralphbean/ansi2html)
- [C](http://ziz.delphigl.com/tool_aha.php) at [github](https://github.com/theZiz/aha) (already mentioned)
- [PERL](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::FromANSI) (also mentioned)
- [sh+AWK](http://pablomarin-garcia.blogspot.com/2011/04/converting-ansi-to-html-how-to-convert.html) at [github](https://github.com/pixelb/scripts/blob/master/scripts/ansi2html.sh)
- and certainly much more.

Answer (score 4):

I have a bookmarklet using such library made for Rancher.

You can find that library inside :-)

```
javascript:var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();oReq.open("GET", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drudru/ansi_up/master/ansi_up.js", true);oReq.onloadend = function (oEvent) {new Function(oReq.responseText)();var el=document.getElementsByTagName("PRE")[0];el.innerHTML=(new AnsiUp).ansi_to_html(el.innerText);};oReq.send();document.body.style="color:white;background-color:black";undefined
```

For humans also readable version ;-)

```
javascript:var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drudru/ansi_up/master/ansi_up.js", true);
oReq.onloadend = function (oEvent) {
    new Function(oReq.responseText)();
    var el = document.getElementsByTagName("PRE")[0];
    el.innerHTML = (new AnsiUp).ansi_to_html(el.innerText);
};
oReq.send();
document.body.style = "color:white;background-color:black";
undefined
```

Comment: Works nicely in Firefox. Not sure why the `undefined` at the end but you can avoid it by wrapping the code in `(function() { /* code goes here */ })()`.

Comment: Sure IIFE is similar option, in case you return anything, it would end as new page content.