# What Mime-Type for text with ANSI Escape-Sequences (Color Codes)

Tags: text, mime-types, color-codes

The log files on our build server come with [ANSI Escape Sequences for colored text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33206814). (As you can tell from the square brackets, semicolons, trailing m's...)

[image]

So this looks ugly (raw view in its own browser tab). Just like if a webserver was passing a jpeg as mimetype `text/plain` to you, or you opening it in notepad.exe... So my question is:

**Is there a mimetype for properly displaying ANSI-color-codes enriched text?**

---

- [same grief](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61109249/444255) – pointing correctly out that strictly speaking it's just an encoding...
- [a bookmarklet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61109249) to help survive

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't any standard, but I personnally use `text/ansi` or `text/ansi-color`.

Comment: I think I'm going to stick with `text/x-ansi` (https://www.digipres.org/formats/mime-types/#text/x-ansi)